# Merge xmls using xslt - based on element values

Tags: xml, xslt

XML1 :  Has Stationid and ports numbers

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <getPublicStationsResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:dictionary:com.chargepoint.webservices" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <stationData>
    <stationID>1:86013</stationID>
    <Port>
       <portNumber>1</portNumber>
       <stationName>EMBASSY TROY / EMBASSY SUITE 1</stationName>
       <Level>L2</Level>
    </Port>
    <Port>
       <portNumber>2</portNumber>
       <stationName>EMBASSY TROY / EMBASSY SUITE 1</stationName>
       <Level>L2</Level>
    </Port>
   </stationData>
   <stationData>
   <stationID>1:2155</stationID>
    <Port>
       <portNumber>1</portNumber>
       <stationName>MAGNA ECAR / TROY VISITOR 01</stationName>
       <Level>L1</Level>
     </Port>
      <Port>
       <portNumber>2</portNumber>
       <stationName>MAGNA ECAR / TROY VISITOR 01</stationName>
        <Level>L2</Level>
      </Port>
    </stationData>
 </getPublicStationsResponse>
```

XML 2 : this xmls has station id , portnumber and portstatus

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:getPublicStationStatusResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:dictionary:com.chargepoint.webservices">

     <stationStatusData>
        <stationID>1:86013</stationID>
        <Port>
           <portNumber>1</portNumber>
           <Status>AVAILABLE</Status>

        </Port>
        <Port>
           <portNumber>2</portNumber>
           <Status>AVAILABLE</Status>

        </Port>
     </stationStatusData>
     <stationStatusData>
        <stationID>1:2155</stationID>
        <Port>
           <portNumber>1</portNumber>
           <Status>AVAILABLE</Status>

        </Port>
        <Port>
           <portNumber>2</portNumber>
           <Status>AVAILABLE</Status>

        </Port>
     </stationStatusData>
  </ns1:getPublicStationStatusResponse>
```

Here :

1 Match  stationID from xml1 and 2 
2 For each port - match portsnumber  and get Status from  second xml, append  status to first xml.

```
 OUTPUT:

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <getPublicStationsResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:dictionary:com.chargepoint.webservices" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <stationData>
        <stationID>1:86013</stationID>
    <Port>
        <portNumber>1</portNumber>
        <Status>AVAILABLE</Status> 
        <stationName>EMBASSY TROY / EMBASSY SUITE 1</stationName>
        <Level>L2</Level>
  </Port>
  <Port>
     <portNumber>2</portNumber>
     <Status>AVAILABLE</Status> 
     <stationName>EMBASSY TROY / EMBASSY SUITE 1</stationName>
     <Level>L2</Level>
  </Port>
</stationData>
<stationData>
  <stationID>1:2155</stationID>
  <Port>
     <portNumber>1</portNumber>
     <Status>AVAILABLE</Status> 
     <stationName>MAGNA ECAR / TROY VISITOR 01</stationName>
     <Level>L1</Level>

  </Port>
  <Port>
     <portNumber>2</portNumber>
     <Status>AVAILABLE</Status> 
     <stationName>MAGNA ECAR / TROY VISITOR 01</stationName>
     <Level>L2</Level>
   </Port>
  </stationData>
</getPublicStationsResponse>
```

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is not clear what you're asking. You should also post what have you tried so far to solve your problem, so we can help you with that. Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are processing the first XML document and passing the path to the second file as a parameter, you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="lookup-path" select="'file2.xml'" />
<xsl:key name="status" match="Port" use="concat(../stationID, '|', portNumber)" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Port">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:variable name="key" select="concat(../stationID, '|', portNumber)" />
        <!-- switch context to lookup document -->
        <xsl:for-each select="document($lookup-path)">
            <Status>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('status', $key)/Status"/>
            </Status>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```